# R if else with multiple conditions for character vectors with NAs

Tags: r

I know there are many questions out there with similar titles, but I can't create a workable solution for my situation. I have a couple of vectors with a combination of text and NA values;

```
DATA <- data.frame("Col.A" = c("Some Text", "Some other text", "Yes", "No", "no", 
NA, "No", "Yes", "yes", NA, NA, NA), "Col.B" = c(NA, NA, "Green", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Blue", "Blue 2", NA, NA, NA))
```

I need to check if `Col.A` includes "Yes", "yes", "No", or "no". If it doesn't then I want to copy the `Col.A` text into `Col.B`. If it has any of those four conditions, I want to leave `Col.B` as it is.

I can get it to work with single `ifelse` statements, (so, only satisfying one of the conditions) but when I try to include multiple conditions it just copies all text across from `Col.A` to `Col.B` (i.e. including the "yes" and "no" entries, wiping the information I want to keep in `Col.B`. I have tried;

```
DATA$Col.B <- if_else((DATA$Col.A != "Yes" | (DATA$Col.A != "yes") |
(DATA$Col.A != "No") | (DATA$Col.A != "no")) , DATA$Col.B, DATA$Col.A)
```

and chaining if else;

```
 if(DATA$Col.A == "Yes"){
       DATA$Col.B <- DATA$Col.B
     } else if(DATA$Col.A == "yes"){
       DATA$Col.B <- DATA$Col.B
     } else if(DATA$Col.A == "No"){
       DATA$Col.B <- DATA$Col.B
     } else if(DATA$Col.A == "no"){
       DATA$Col.B <- DATA$Col.B
     } else {
       DATA$Col.B <- DATA$Col.A
     }
```

But no luck. Any pointers are appreciated!

Comment: there's a logic error in your code, replace `!=` with `==`  will do, and the function is `ifelse`, not `if_else`

Comment: @TCZhang `if_else` is from `dplyr`

Comment: @TCZhang either `!=` or `==` give the same result; all of `Col.A` is copied to `Col.B`.

Comment: @EcologyTom no, they do not give the same result, see my answer below.

Comment: @TCZhang, apologies, you are correct. I'm not sure why it wasn't working with my real data, but with further testing it is behaving as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `tidyverse` approach

```
library(tidyverse)
DATA %>%
    mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
    mutate(Col.B = if_else(Col.A %in% c("Yes", "yes", "No", "no"), Col.B, Col.A))
#             Col.A           Col.B
#1        Some Text       Some Text
#2  Some other text Some other text
#3              Yes           Green
#4               No            <NA>
#5               no            <NA>
#6             <NA>            <NA>
#7               No            <NA>
#8              Yes            Blue
#9              yes          Blue 2
#10            <NA>            <NA>
#11            <NA>            <NA>
#12            <NA>            <NA>
```

In base R using `grepl`

```
transform(DATA, Col.B = ifelse(
    grepl("([Yy]es|[Nn]o)", Col.A),
    as.character(Col.B), as.character(Col.A)))
```

or similar to the `tidyverse` approach using `%in%` with `tolower` (thanks @DJV)

```
transform(DATA, Col.B = ifelse(
    tolower(Col.A) %in% c("yes", "no"),
    as.character(Col.B), as.character(Col.A)))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I want the opposite of this; leave `Col.B` as it is if there are any "yes" or "no" entries in `Col.A`, only copy across if there is other text.

Comment: @EcologyTom Ah I see. Sorry my bad. I've made an edit.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Oops. Thanks & fixed.

Comment: @MauritsEvers instead of using all the possible options of capitalized/non-capitalized "yes" and "no", you can use `tolower` or `toupper`.

Comment: Thanks @MauritsEvers, this works nicely. I opted for your last approach. And thanks for the tip, @DJV - I had no idea about `tolower`, will be able to use that in other code too.

Comment: @EcologyTom you're welcome :) I found it very useful when I have to deal with file name/path

Comment: Just for info for any future readers of this answer, I was able to drop the `transform` part, and just directly assign the `ifelse` statement to `DATA$Col.B`

Answer (score 0):

Using base R: you can use `grepl`

```
 DATA = rapply(DATA,as.character,"factor",how="replace")#CHANGE FACTOR COLUMNS TO CHARACTER

 transform(DATA,Col.B=ifelse(grepl("\\b(Yes|no)\\b",Col.A,ignore.case = T),Col.B,Col.A))
             Col.A           Col.B
1        Some Text       Some Text
2  Some other text Some other text
3              Yes           Green
4               No            <NA>
5               no            <NA>
6             <NA>            <NA>
7               No            <NA>
8              Yes            Blue
9              yes          Blue 2
10            <NA>            <NA>
11            <NA>            <NA>
12            <NA>            <NA>
```

Comment: This adds a new column `Col` instead of replacing entries in `Col.B`; you also don't need to `$`-index `Col.A` inside `transform`. Not sure whether this is a significant improvement over the `grepl` solution I give;-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my comment, I changed `!=` to `==` and get the same result as other answers and as described in your original question.

```r
DATA <- data.frame("Col.A" = c("Some Text", "Some other text", "Yes", "No", "no", 
NA, "No", "Yes", "yes", NA, NA, NA), "Col.B" = c(NA, NA, "Green", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"Blue", "Blue 2", NA, NA, NA),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

DATA$newCol.B <- ifelse((DATA$Col.A == "Yes" | (DATA$Col.A == "yes") |
(DATA$Col.A == "No") | (DATA$Col.A == "no")) , DATA$Col.B, DATA$Col.A)

DATA
#>              Col.A  Col.B        newCol.B
#> 1        Some Text   <NA>       Some Text
#> 2  Some other text   <NA> Some other text
#> 3              Yes  Green           Green
#> 4               No   <NA>            <NA>
#> 5               no   <NA>            <NA>
#> 6             <NA>   <NA>            <NA>
#> 7               No   <NA>            <NA>
#> 8              Yes   Blue            Blue
#> 9              yes Blue 2          Blue 2
#> 10            <NA>   <NA>            <NA>
#> 11            <NA>   <NA>            <NA>
#> 12            <NA>   <NA>            <NA>
```

Created on 2018-07-18 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).